# Searching in iOS apps

Tags: ios, search

I want to store about 10000 strings in my iOS app.  I want the ability to quickly search these strings (similar to searching on the devices themselves when you swipe to the left of the home screen).  Searching should include a form of "suggest" or auto-complete.  For example typing "food" into the search box should bring up a list containing "food stores" "food recipes" etc.

How can I implement this type of search?  Perhaps a sqlLite database and ... ?

Cheers!

Comment: you might want to implement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Yes I was considering this.  But I figured the SDK will probably do it for me somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a case you can follow two ways:

1. Integrate Core Data as Diederik Hoogenboom suggested.
2. Use filteredArrayUsingPredicate method of NSArray and build a predicate for your needs as described in following document [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html)

   I am personally prefer option #2, it is easier to start and depends on solution's performance and memory footprint you can always switch to more complex #1 option.

Comment: Core Data really isn't nearly as complex as it seems. It was created to make the job for the programmer much much easier than it would be if the programmer were to implement a store manually, and it does its job well. I would recommend checking out this fantastic tutorial to get you up to speed: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started